# Opensuse Leap 15.0: Default audio device not being used by Chrome

Tags: opensuse, pulseaudio, chrome

I have the default output set to my speakers, but sometimes, Chrome will ignore this and use my second audio output, my usb headphones. I originally had Tumbleweed installed on my desktop, where this issue did not occur. The version of Chrome has remained the same, so I do not believe it's related to chrome.

The only way I can get Chrome to use the default output is by, using the audio widget, swapping the default device to my other device and back to the original one. (Edit: pavucontrol has the same effect).

Edit: Also, if I open a new tab, it just goes back to using the other audio device instead of the current default. So I have to repeat the above process every time I open a new tab.

Edit2: Paused a Youtube video and walked away to use the bathroom, came back, unpaused the video and the audio output again went back to the other output. It turns out opening a new tab doesn't fallback to the wrong device, it's time based.

Edit3: I've restarted pulseaudio with verbose logging, but have yet to have this issue reoccur, so maybe that information is useful.

Edit4: Readded relevant information to the question that was erroneously removed by a mod.

Comment: Do you see this changing of the audio device reflected in `pavucontrol`?

Comment: No, the default device does not change in either the widget or pavucontrol

Comment: As in, my speakers remain as the default device, even after chrome switches output.

Answer (score 0):

At first try to set a "preferred" audio card using
System Settings -> Multimedia -> Audio and Video
Select "Audio Playback" node and move desired audio device to the top.
Then you can apply this list to all.

If you get what you want "systemwide" then you can revisit those settings to change audio devices order for different categories.

Remember if you change a device in pulse audio settings, next time you will restart a playback a "preferred" device will be selected again.